# How do I make the child index reset to 0 for each new parent section?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexing, reset

I'm using the `index` of an item to add an animation delay to elements on my website.

Here's the HTML and JS

```
<div>
     <div class="section section-1">
          <div class="item item-1">
          </div>
          <div class="item item-2">
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="section section-2">
          <div class="item item-1">
          </div>
          <div class="item item-2">
          </div>
          <div class="item item-3">
          </div>
          <div class="item item-4">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
const AnimatedElements = document.querySelectorAll(".section .item");

AnimatedElements.forEach((AnimatedElement, index) => {
    AnimatedElement.style.setProperty('--index-delay', ([index] * 250) + "ms");
});
```

Now, this does work. However, The issue I am having is the JS reads the item index as one Array (I.E [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) rather than two separate arrays within their respective sections (I.E section 1 [0, 1], Section 2 [0, 1, 2, 3]).

Is there any way I can make the index reset to 0 for each new section? As otherwise the animation delay just gets longer and longer the further you scroll down the page.

Edit: I've managed to get the issue fix. However, I have now applied the JS to the columns within the section as well as the items and I am now experiencing the same issue as before.

Here's the updated HTML and JS

```
<div>
     <div class="section section-1">
          <div class="column column-1">
               <div class="item item-1">
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column column-2">
               <div class="item item-2">
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="section section-2">
          <div class="column column-1">
               <div class="item item-1">
               </div>
               <div class="item item-2">
               </div>
               <div class="item item-3">
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column column-2">
               <div class="item item-4">
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
const Sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
const Columns = document.querySelectorAll(".section .column");

Columns.forEach(Column => {
    const AnimatedElements = Column.querySelectorAll(".item");
    AnimatedElements.forEach((AnimatedElement, index) => {
        AnimatedElement.style.setProperty('--index-delay', (index * 250) + "ms");
    });
});

Sections.forEach(Section => {
    const AnimatedColumns = Section.querySelectorAll(".column");
    AnimatedColumns.forEach((AnimatedColumn, index) => {
        AnimatedColumn.style.setProperty('--index-delay', (index * 250) + "ms");
    });
});
```

As said before the issue is doing the exact same thing that it did before where the JS reads the column index as one Array (I.E [0, 1, 2, 3]) rather than two separate arrays within their respective sections (I.E section 1 [0, 1], Section 2 [0, 1]).

Any help to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `index` in an array? `[index] * 250` should be `index * 250`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested loops. The outer loop is for the sections, the inner loop is for the items. The item indexes will start at 0 in each section.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

sections.forEach(section => {
  const AnimatedElements = section.querySelectorAll(".item");
  console.log([...AnimatedElements]);
  AnimatedElements.forEach((AnimatedElement, index) => {
    AnimatedElement.style.setProperty('--index-delay', (index * 250) + "ms");
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="section section-1">
    <div class="item item-1">1A
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">1B
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section section-2">
    <div class="item item-1">2A
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">2B
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">2C
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">2D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This hasn't worked and all the items are still being put into one array. Is there anything that may have been missed to stop this from working for me?

Comment: There are no arrays anywhere in your code. except for the erroneous `[index]`.

Comment: I've added code that logs each group of items as an array, you can see that there are two arrays.

Comment: Sorry I've just rechecked my code. I did the Const wrong and put const "AnimatedElements = document.querySelectorAll(".item");" rather than "const AnimatedElements = section.querySelectorAll(".item");" like how you had it. That's it now working correctly. Many thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hey, I've just run into a basically identical issue and experiencing the exact same issue as before but this time the code you sent hasn't helped. Could you take a look at the original post, I've added an edit with the problem I'm having and your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is different because you have 2 levels of nesting. I'm not clear on when you want the indexes to reset. You reset the item indexes to 0 for each column, and you reset the column indexes to 0 for each section.

Comment: I don't know what `--index-delay` is, so I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. But it seems strange that you're animating each level independently of its parent's timing.

Comment: Yes I want the column index to reset for each section but it's currently not doing that even though the code is the exact same as the code for the items it combines the columns into 1 array again. Which is why I don't understand why it's not working. The index delay is for a CSS ```animation-delay``` to make each item animate when on screen. The ```--Index-delay``` creates a delay depending on the index of the item to create a staggered, fade-in effect when scrolling through the page. Here's an example on codepen to show what I mean -https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/LVLqQV?css-preprocessor=sass

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see in the codepen. When I scroll to the bottom I see 01, 02, 03 and they fade in at different times.

Comment: The codepen doesn't have the new code you added in the question. Anyway, I think you need to post a new question if this is a different problem.